# why i cannot make hole on the mesh?

Tags: modeling

why i cannot make hole on the mesh?. I have check both mesh rotation scale, Face pointing outside. No double verts seen.

[image]

[image]

I want to make a cylinder hole but it creates a square hole. Any suggestion or help whats going wrong with my mesh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of N-gon topoology.
[image]

It's a bug in Boolean modifier I think, but still.
I see 4 solutions:

1. Retopo your mesh so it contains only quads.
2. You can use Fast method of Boolean modifier. There's still an issue but less noticable:
   [image]
3. Add a circle instead of a cylinder and use a Shrinkwrap modifier. You'll get a nice cut:
   [image]
4. Use add-ons like BoxCutter. As I know, it deals with N-gons nicely. But the add-on is expensive :(